# How do I get a complete list from a XML-file by using LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have xml-file looks like this:

```
<Knowledge>
  <Group name="Methods and Techniques">
    <Item name="OO" level="1" />
    <Item name="Dataflow Diagram" level="4" />
    <Item naeme="SDM" level="5" />
  </Group>
  <Group name="Languages">
    <Item name="C#" level="1" />
    <Item name="Delphi" level="1" />
    <Item name="Visual Basic" level="4" />  
  </Group>
</Knowledge>
```

... and I want to create  a list by using a LINQ-query.

```
 var queryKnowledge = (from item in _Document.Descendants("Knowledge").Elements("Group")
                             select new
                             {
                                 Group = (string)item.Attribute("name"),
                                 Name = (string)item.Element("Item").Attribute("name"),
                                 Level = (string)item.Element("Item").Attribute("level")
                             }).AsQueryable();
```

But I get a list of two items. First of each group.

But how I get a list looks this?

```
Group                  Name              Level
Methods and Techniques OO                1
Methods and Techniques Dataflow Diagram  4
Methods and Techniques SDM               5
Languages              C#                1
Languages              Delphi            1
Languages              Visual Basic      4
```

What do I have to change in my LINQ-query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to flattern your hierarchy by using `SelectMany` Linq method or use `Elements` method, provided by LINQ to XML, which do the same job.

```
//xml variable contains string representation of your xml
//use XDocument.Load(filePath) to load xml having path to a file
var nodes = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                     .Descendants("Knowledge")
                     .Elements("Group")
                     .Elements("Item");

var queryKnowledge = from item in nodes
                             select new
                             {
                                 Group = (string)item.Parent.Attribute("name"),
                                 Name = (string)item.Attribute("name"),
                                 Level = (string)item.Attribute("level")
                             };
```

prints

```
Group                  Name             Level 
Methods and Techniques OO               1 
Methods and Techniques Dataflow Diagram 4 
Methods and Techniques null             5 
Languages              C#               1 
Languages              Delphi           1 
Languages              Visual Basic     4
```

`null` is because your attribute in one Item has name as `naeme`. You also don't need `AsQueryable` here, as far as I can see.

As  Chris kindly noted, you can use next code snippet to gather required nodes and then apply the same `Select` projection.

```
var nodes = XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("Item");
```

Comment: You could also just select _Document.Descendants("Item"), assuming that this is the whole schema.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I had to change a little bit "var _Document = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/App_Data/Kennis.xml"));" ... and then: "var nodes = _Document" and the rest is the same.

Comment: @user1531040 ok, just `_Document` doesn't seemed to be a good name for a local variable, so I've use mine. Anyway, glad to help

Answer (score 3):

Actually since your example is pretty simple, you can just get the `Item` nodes by calling `Elements("Item")` and use Parent to get the Group name:

```
    var queryKnowledge = (from item in xDoc.Element("Knowledge").Elements("Group").Elements("Item")
                          select new
                          {
                              Group = (string)item.Parent.Attribute("name"),
                              Name = (string)item.Attribute("name"),
                              Level = (string)item.Attribute("level")
                          }).AsQueryable();
```

Note I changed first call to Element() instead of Descendants() assuming per your example you only have one such element.

Comment: Nice solution. And it looks quite simple.